# Free SaaS machine learning that exports to PMML, with bayes, random forest, NN, SVM, and decision trees

Tags: gratis, machine-learning, saas

I know there are many machine learning libraries available to run ML algorithms in our local computer. I am looking for a free cloud based machine learning service available which:

- doesn't require a credit card during sign up (Amazon and Azure require credit cards).
- allows export of ML model as PMML or other file types
- has naive bayes, random forest, neural network, SVM, and decision trees.

The only service which I found  was bigml.com (free has a file size limit of 16MB) but it seems it has only one ML model and that is decision trees: it lacks naive bayes, random forest, neural network, and SVM.

Comment: What's wrong with the locally installed ones?

Answer (score 2):

Azure ML offers limited guest access (no credit card needed).

BigML also provides:

- **Ensembles of decision trees** (**bagging** and **random decision forests**) for classification and regression tasks.
- **Logistic regression** for classification tasks.
- **K-means** and **g-means** for cluster analysis.
- **Isolation forests** for anomaly detection.
- **Magnum opus** for association discovery.

BigML free development account has no limits in the total number of tasks. It only limits the size of the input datasets. You can keep your account forever and use as many datasets as you want. The only thing you need to consider is that in development mode, there're also some limits in the parameters of the algorithms (number of models of an ensemble, etc) but they are good enough to give you a good impression of what you can do with the service.

What BigML offers for FREE is actually quite good. Cloud-based Machine Learning services abstract away the underlying infrastructure, configuration, maintenance, etc. When you use local libraries you need to deal with all of them what can become quite painful.